# How to programmatically generate R codes and directory structures with template

Tags: r, shiny, templating

I have the following Shiny-app, organize the following way

```
-- base_app
   |-- server.R
   |-- ui.R
   `-- www
```

For example, `server.R` contains this lines:

```
infile <- "foo.txt"
# do something with infile
```

I'm looking for a way to automatically generate the app directory and the file content. For example, if we define 2 parameters:

1. App name `mycool_app`
2. Input file: `bar.txt`

afterwards it will generate this based on the template defined in `base_app`.

```
-- mycool_app
   |-- server.R
   |-- ui.R
   `-- www
```

And the new `server.R` will contain `infile <- "bar.txt"`.

I looked at
[whisker](https://github.com/edwindj/whisker). But it doesn't provide the template encoded inside file, only through string. I'm thinking of the capability ala [Python's Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/).

What are the best way to do it in R?

---

**Update**:

Another example for `ui.R`:

```
# Example of ui.R
# Choices differs from analysis to analysis
# Hand coded 
# ---------------------------
choices_list <- list(
                "A. Rumef.XXX vs Salt"            = "Group_A.Rumef.XXX_vs_Salt.iv",
                "B. Bra.XXX vs Salt"              = "Group_B.Bra.XXX_vs_Salt.iv",
                "C. Salt.Rumef vs Bra"            = "Group_C.Salt.Rumef_vs_Bra.iv",
                "D. XXX.Rumef vs Bra"             = "Group_D.XXX.Rumef_vs_Bra.iv"
                                                 )
selected_choices <- "Group_A.Rumef.XXX_vs_Salt.iv"
analysis_name <- "Cool Analysis"
fc_slider_threshold <- 0.8

# Do more things with those variables.
```

Content of `choices_list`, `selected_choices`, `analysis_name`, `fc_slider_threshold` will be supplied to be included in the newly generated `mycool_app`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What is the difference between your question and simply copying the entire app folder from one location to another?

Comment: @Florian I have many parameter-set and with that I want to create multiple apps. I want to automate that Shiny-apps generation.

Comment: Sorry, I am still not 100% clear. I see a server.R which contains `infile <- "foo.txt"`, and that server.R file is also created in a different folder. What kind of parameters do you have and what kind of behavior do you expect them to perform? Right now it looks like file.copy() would work.

Comment: @pdubois are you looking for R or bash solution?

Comment: @PoGibas R, but welcome bash if it's reasonable.

Answer (score 10):

not sure if I correctly understand what you need, but this piece of code seems to be doing what you want

```
genAppStr <- function(appname, infile) {
  dir.create(appname)
  dir.create(paste0(appname, "/www"))
  file.create(paste0(appname, "/", c("server.R", "ui.R")))
  writeLines(paste0("infile <- '", infile, "'"), paste0(appname, "/server.R"))
}

genAppStr("mycool_app", "bar.txt")
```

Or do you want to insert the contents of bar.txt into server.R?

With regard to the updated question:

```
genAppStr1 <- function(appname, infile, pars) {
  dir.create(appname)
  dir.create(paste0(appname, "/www"))
  file.create(paste0(appname, "/", c("server.R", "ui.R")))
  infilec <- readLines(infile)
  glued <- sapply(infilec, function(x) with(pars, glue(x)), USE.NAMES = FALSE)
  writeLines(as.character(glued), paste0(appname, "/server.R"))
}
```

Usage:

```
library(glue)

ch <- c("A. Rumef.XXX vs Salt"            = "Group_A.Rumef.XXX_vs_Salt.iv",
  "B. Bra.XXX vs Salt"              = "Group_B.Bra.XXX_vs_Salt.iv",
  "C. Salt.Rumef vs Bra"            = "Group_C.Salt.Rumef_vs_Bra.iv",
  "D. XXX.Rumef vs Bra"             = "Group_D.XXX.Rumef_vs_Bra.iv")

options(useFancyQuotes = FALSE)

vsQuote <- Vectorize(sQuote, USE.NAMES = FALSE)

makeChoiceList <- function(ch) {
  nms <- vsQuote(names(ch))
  chs <- vsQuote(ch)
  chnm <- paste(nms, chs, sep = " = ")
  paste0('list(', paste(chnm, collapse = ","), ')')
}

genAppStr1(
  "mycool_app", "infile.txt", 
  pars = list(
    par1 = makeChoiceList(ch),
    par2 = sQuote("Group_A.Rumef.XXX_vs_Salt.iv"),
    par3 = sQuote("Cool Analysis"),
    par4 = 0.8
  )
)
```

and the contents of `infile.txt` are

```
choices_list <- {par1}
selected_choices <- {par2}
analysis_name <- {par3}
fc_slider_threshold <- {par4}
```

Comment: Thanks. What if I have more complex server code (multiple lines etc.) It would be more convenient to have a template no?

Comment: Maybe you can use glue for that. Can you give a simple example of what kind of server.R you would be generating?